# Looking string inside cell Text (VB)

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm looping row inside sheet and I want to find string inside some text:

```
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lrk = wsK.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr --looping list
  look_name = UCase(ws.Range("E" & i).Value)

    For j = 2 To lrk --loop patern value
    look_text = UCase(wsK.Range("A" & j).Value)

        If look_name Like "*look_text*" Then --if found
            ws.Range("AB" & i) = wsK.Range("B" & j).Value --to do
            Exit For
        End If

    Next j
Next i
```

I think something wrong I did with `"*look_text*"`

If `look_name = "New city"` and `look_text = "city"`, it's not going into IF.

Comment: Why do you think you did something wrong with `"*look_text*"`?

Comment: On my test data it's not working, maybe somewhere else is mostake....

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: You should probably read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your post to provide information that will enable the group to help you.

Comment: It's not going inside if , when the string is inside my text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by changing

```
If look_name Like "*look_text*" Then
```

to

```
If look_name Like "*" & look_text & "*" Then
```

Comment: Thank you @Vadim for adjust answer

Answer (score 3):

Another option, since you are adding wild-card `*` in the beginning and the end of your `String`, is to use `Instr` Function.

```
If Instr(look_name, look_text) > 0 Then
```

---

**Edit 1**: with text provided from PO

```
If InStr("abcabc testa abcbc", "test") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Instr Works"
End If
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it's not working, when I change it to `If InStr(look_name, look_text) > 0` then is working correctly

Comment: @4est it's `"look_text"` , you need to add the `"`

Comment: no, I need to use `&` to connect parameter, without this is not working

Comment: @4est if you can give me the string you need to check trust me it will work. The `Instr` will give you the same result as using `Like "*" & look_text & "*"`

Comment: I have checked all possibility with string (at beginning, in the middle, at end) and it&#39;s not working, sorry

Comment: @4est , OK, first time I've heard of `Instr` not working, if you want, read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: try: into `abcabc testa abcbc` find `test`....maybe I have missing somethink? 
 vbBinaryCompare or vbTextCompare?

Comment: @4est look at Edit 1 in my answer